# Outputting time in minutes and seconds C++

Tags: c++

Firstly, I know homework is looked down on but I'm not asking anyone to complete this for me, just to guide a little. I've looked online but answers vary and are different and because I'm new it's a little confusing.

I need to make a program where the user inputs the name of a snail and the time taken for it to complete a lap of a track... The time needs to be put in in seconds but put out in minutes&seconds.

Currently have;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>

int main() {


    char snail_name[15] = "";
    char time_taken[1000] = "";

    printf("\nEnter name of snail: ");
    scanf("%s", &snail_name);
    printf("Time to finish course:");
    scanf("%s", &time_taken);
    printf("%s ran the course in\n", &snail_name,&time_taken);
}
```

Currently have:

[image]

Which means I need it to say ran the course in 5 minutes(300 was entered for example), although the code currently doesn't work for that but I could figure that out probably, just need to know how I go about converting a number input by the user to be shown in minutes and seconds.

Comment: Well, you have 60 seconds / minute. So knowing this and some basic math you can convert it. If you need another hint, just reply, and I'll update with slightly more information.

Comment: Also, as an Aside to this question I would recommend not using C style strings (aka Character arrays) considering they are more error prone and less flexible than the std::string type. Same goes for the printf function, since std::cout is type safe and also less error prone. But that is just a note for future reference.

Comment: Thanks! I'm literally completely new to this so it's all a bit confusing at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accept the total time as an integer instead of a string, and then you can divide it by 60 to get whole minutes and modulus of 60 to get the remaining seconds:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main() {
    char snail_name[15] = "";
    int time_taken = 0;

    printf("\nEnter name of snail: ");
    scanf("%15s", snail_name);
    printf("Time to finish course:");
    scanf("%d", &time_taken);
    printf("%s ran the course in %d:%d\n", &snail_name, time_taken / 60, time_taken % 60);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you have a working answer but if you are learning `C++` rather use `iostream` instead of `printf` and `scanf` which are from `C`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{ 
    std::string snail_name;
    int time_taken = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter name: ";
    std::cin >> snail_name;

    std::cout << "Time to finish: ";
    std::cin >> time_taken;

    std::cout << snail_name << " ran the course in " << time_taken / 60 << ":" << time_taken % 60 << std::endl;
}
```

If the assignment states you have to use `printf` and `scanf` then you can ignore this answer. But in general I would recommend use `C++` as far as possible when trying to learn `C++`.

I related video from [CppCon 2015: Kate Gregory “Stop Teaching C"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) (you can even pass the link on to a lecturer/teacher)